# Wait for all async methods finish

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, java-threads

I wrote method that contains two async methods that create connection with firebase. I want to finish the method after all the async methods finish. How can i do this?
If it was one async method so i was create callBack interface but is not helpful in this situation.

For example:

```
 public void method(String teamID1,String teamID2)
{
    final ArrayList<String> usersID = new ArrayList<>();

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase1 =  getDatabaseReference(ConstantNames.ROLE_PATH).child ( teamID1 );
    mDatabase1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usersID.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase2 =  getDatabaseReference(ConstantNames.ROLE_PATH).child ( 2 );
    mDatabase2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usersID.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

(This method is just for illustration)

I want finish this method when listener of mDatabase1 and listener of mDatabase2 called.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the brand new `get()` method for this. This method does almost the same as `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, but:

- It fixes a race condition that may return stale data from the disk cache.
- It returns a `Task<DataSnapshot>`.

That last bit is relevant for you, as it allows you to then use `Tasks.whenAll()` on the tasks for your two database calls here.

Also see:

- [What is the difference between get() and addListenerForSingleValueEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072471/what-is-the-difference-between-get-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent), for an example of the new `get()` API vs the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` API
- The reference documentation for [`Tasks.whenAll`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)).
- [Become a Firebase Taskmaster! (Part 4: Multi-Taskmastering)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-4.html) for an example of using `Tasks.whenAll()`.