# Firebase .get() vs .once() - What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get) but I don't understand:
What is the difference between .get() and .once()?

My understanding is that `.get()` reads from the server, and then from the local storage, and `.once()` reads only from the local storage. I have used`.once()` to retrieve values without setting up a listener like `.on()` and it seems to be retrieving values from the server (realtime database) that I haven't retrieved before so I'm not sure what it means when it says it only searches the local storage... It seems like it is in fact getting values from the server.

Please clarify when to use one vs the other.

I have not used `.get()` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical difference per [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s answer below, but in practice, I receive a ton of "Client is offline" Errors for seemingly no reason when using `.get()` in Firebase Functions.

I recommend using `.once()`

See issue here for reference: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/VpQms_TnBOw?pli=1

Answer (score 11):

*firebaser here*

In practice, in the web SDK, there is no practical difference between `get()` and `once('value'`, since the web SDK for Realtime Database. does not support disk persistence.

We mostly decided to add the `get()` method to the JavaScript SDK, as we were adding similar methods to the iOS and Android SDKs, where there is a real, but subtle, difference between the methods. For a longer explanation of that, see [What is the difference between get() and addListenerForSingleValueEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072471/what-is-the-difference-between-get-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent) (`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is the Android variant of JavaScript's `once()` call).

Comment: Thanks Frank :) It sounds by Ganbayar's response that there is a difference: it is that `.once()` would be more cost effective to use if you already somehow had the most recent response in cache. Though without a listener set up, when I run a `.once()` how would it know if it has the most recent data in cache? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I've worked with the engineers on defining this API, so I know pretty well how this API works across all platforms.  The JavaScript SDK doesn't have a disk cache, so the only way to have the value already is to have it in memory, which means you need to have an active `on()` listener, and that then also explains why both `once()` and `get()` will return the in-memory value. If either of them does something different or retrieves the value from the network in that case, it's a bug in the implementation. For example: such a bug briefly existed in the Android implementation, but has been fixed.

Comment: Note: I should've said "I know pretty well how this API is *supposed* to work across all platforms", because bugs are always possible of course. 

Answer (score 8):

`.get()` will always try to make a call to the database, IF only when if it is not able to reach the database or similar, it will fall back to the local cache.

on the other hand;
`.once()` will always try to get the value from the local cache, instead of making the call to the database, making it cost effective.

You can also look at the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html) on the method which makes it more clear:

```
.get() 
Gets the most up-to-date result for this query.

Returns Promise<DataSnapshot>
A promise which resolves to the resulting DataSnapshot if a value is available, 
or rejects if the client is unable to return a value 
(e.g., if the server is unreachable and there is nothing cached).

.once()
Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, 
and then stops listening.

This is equivalent to calling on(), and then calling off() inside 
the callback function.
```

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Great answer Ganbayar!

Comment: Thank you! The reference is very helpful. I'm still learning how to use docs XD

Comment: @Ganbayar That reference for .once() does not mention local cache with a single word, what part of it is your reply based on?