# Cloud Function: ERROR Client is offline when trying to read from Firebase RTDB (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a schedule function for my Firebase project. The function will read data from Firebase RTDB. However, I've been getting a Client is offline error in the function logs. Is there any way I can solve this problem? I've tried including and excluding queries. Here's the code:

```
firebase.database("some link here")
        .ref().child("ticket").get().then((value) => {
            value.forEach((element) => {
                console.log(element.key);
            })
        });
```

I've tried looking for solutions, but still haven't managed to find one. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I've recently seen some people having this problem and from my testing it seem to happen when the client hasn't been able to establish a connection yet when you first call `get()`.

Until a fix is available, the best workaround is to call `once()` which is pretty much the same on Cloud Functions and on other JavaScript environments anyway.

Also see: [Firebase .get() vs .once() - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610191/209103)