# Firebase cache .indexOn in Application Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for my flutter application and I have created a .IndexOn.

The query is working with OrderByChild, the problem is when loading the query, it loads only Cashe.

Example, when I open the application on device 1, and at the same time I create a record through another device 2. Device 1 only loads new data if I delete the application cache.

I'm using PersitenceEnabled, but the problem only happens with queries with .IndexOn

```
"users": {
".indexOn": ["isPsycho","currentPsycho"]
}
```

Query I'm Using

```
await databaseReference
      .orderByChild('isPsycho')
      .equalTo(true)
      .once()
      .then((DataSnapshot snapshot)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how you load the data? I highly recommend following the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to maximize the chances that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using disk cache combined with `once()` unfortunately can return stale data to your listeners. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195) for an explanation why that is: [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195)

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072471/what-is-the-difference-between-get-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent) on the new `get()` method that addresses this issue. The `get()` method is not available in Flutter yet, so for the moment your only options are to either use `onValue()` *or* to disable disk persistence.

I just added this feature request to [implement `get()` method from native SDKs for Realtime Database](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/6089) to the Github repo, so check there for the latest status.